# can I send a user to the iPhone's lock-screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've seen an app that activates the lock-screen after showing a local notification (so the user has to enter the passcode).

... and now I wonder how they did this, since I need this kind of functionality for one of my projects. It might even pass Apple's review process because it does make sense for this app... (and, yes, I'm aware that Apple might reject it, but I'd like to give it a shot).

How would I do this???

Comment: App or it didn't happen (coincidental auto-lock; app defined PIN & customized lock screen)

Comment: Imagine the misery this could cause. Write an app that locks the screen. Unlock it, the app launches, and the screen locks. Repeat forever. Definitely won't be permitted in the App Store.

Comment: You most like likely didn't see the app go to your lock screen, only a lock-screen like duplicate created by the app, for the app.

Comment: It's a parental control app called «Time Lock» and it certainly doesn't fake the lock screen as I have to type in my own code. It also wouldn't work with a duplicate screen as the lock screen appears when the app is in the background (firing a local notification and then goes to the lock screen). Unfortunately, the app isn't free, so I doubt you guys will invest money just to check what I claim (it's true, though, believe me :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible as the framework that handles this is private.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8.1 does not offer API to do this. Most likely you have seen an App implementing its own lock screen. You will need to implement something similar.

You can find examples on GitHub, e.g. https://github.com/venmo/VENTouchLock

Comment: see my comment above